# How do I implement base members in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want a base class to share its member variables with the child class, how do I do that?

Example code:

```
var register = function(f){
    setTimeout(function(){
        f('123');
    }, 5000);
};

var base = function(){
    var self = this;

    this.objects = [];

    this.events = {
        token : register(function(data){
             self.objects.push(data); //THIS WONT MODIFY THE child VERSION OF objects, how do I do that??
        })
    };
};

var child = function(){
    var self = this;

    this.objects = [2, 3, 4];
};
// child inherits from base
child.prototype = new base;
child.prototype.constructor = child;
child.prototype.parent = base.prototype;

var d = new child();
var e = new child();

setTimeout(function(){
    $('body').html(d.objects.join(",") + " " + e.objects.join(","));
    //prints out: "2,3,4 2,3,4" i want: "2,3,4,123 2,3,4,123"
}, 6000);
```

As you can see there, the base class has its own implementation of objects and that is separate from the childs version. How do I fix that?

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8094g8ta/

Comment: You want to have a variable in the Parent constructor and want that to be available to the Child also?

Comment: @thefourtheye yes, pretty much (but also must have the caveat that altering the variable from one child has no effect on the other child)

Comment: You mean, like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/thefourtheye/8094g8ta/2/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is have the child constructor call the parent constructor so that the parent initialization runs for each child:

```
var child = function () {
    base.call(this);

    this.objects.push(2, 3, 4);
};
```

Once you have this, it doesn't make sense to use `new base` to create the child prototype since it's redundant, and in fact, calling constructors to create prototypes is now an outdated practice. Instead, use `Object.create()`:

```
// child inherits from base
child.prototype = Object.create(base.prototype);
```

Putting it all together:

```js
var register = function(f) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        f('123');
    }, 5000);
};

var base = function() {
    var self = this;

    this.objects = [];

    this.events = {
        token: register(function(data) {
            self.objects.push(data);
        })
    };
};

var child = function() {
    base.call(this);

    this.objects.push(2, 3, 4);
};
// child inherits from base
child.prototype = Object.create(base.prototype);
child.prototype.constructor = child;
child.prototype.parent = base.prototype;

var d = new child();
var e = new child();

setTimeout(function() {
    $('body').html(d.objects.join(",") + " " + e.objects.join(","));
}, 6000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Actually, yeah, can you explain how `base.call(this)` makes this work? What is it doing?

Comment: `base.call(this)` runs the `base` function with the current `this` (which in this case is a `child`) as its `this` value. So the initialization actions inside the `base()` function are performed on the newly created object and it gets its own `objects` and `events` properties. This is basically the same as calling a parent constructor from a child constructor in a typical class-based language.